# webTRIS APInot detecting reports from today

Tags: python

I am contacting the UK webTRIS API through pyTRIS (the module the database and processes the data partially automatically, for python). When I enter any date from (ddmmyyyy) around this month it replies with the error:

```
    raise DataUnavailableError('No data found.')
pytris.errors.DataUnavailableError: No data found.
```

My code is as follows:

```
api = API()
daily = api.daily_reports()

result = daily.get(
    sites='6337, 6339, 6362, 6333, 6364, 6368, 6367, 6368, 6370, 6372, 6374, 6376' , start_date='07072023', end_date='07072023'
)
```

I have been unable to find much documentation about this module and API.
I suspect that the error is in the way the module requests data from the API.